# How to pass data to angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs and I am able to list out my data I receive via a REST API.  I display the data in a table and in one of the columns I want to have a delete button that will eventually make a DELETE call to remove that particular record from the database.  Here is the HTML I using:

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="hosts" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat="x in displayedCollection">
            <td>{{x.hostname}}</td>
            <td>{{x.ipaddress}}</td>
            <td>{{x.macaddress}}</td>            
            <td>
                <button 
                   type="button" 
                   class="btn btn-default btn-sm" 
                   ng-click="delete_record({{x._id}})">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    ...    
   </table>
```

This gives me this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 16 of the expression [delete_record({{x._id}})] starting at [{x._id}})].
```

My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller("meanVoyCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
    ...        
    $scope.delete_record  = function(id) {alert("id is ["+id+"]");};
    ...
});
```

For now I'd be happy if I could just an `alert` pop up display the `_id` of the record to be deleted.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the curlys, just do:

```
ng-click="delete_record(x._id)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the {{}} around x._id. Should look like this:

```
ng-click="delete_record(x._id)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use curly braces if you are outside an angular directive ('ng-repeat' in this case). It serves as a way to use your angular data or controller code. Because you are inside an angular directive already, the curly braces are not needed. Your button html would become:

```
ng-click="delete_record(x._id)">
```

Comment: _"You only need to use curly braces if you are outside an angular directive"_ - Whatever you mean by outside, the statement is simply not true. Whether or not curly braces can be used depends on what a directive expects. A bunch of them **do** expect templates, `ngHref` e.g. The reason the OP's code doesn't work is that the expression is parsed before it has been interpolated. Otherwise it would work even with the curly braces.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't feel going into that much detail on this simple of a problem was necessary since he is not using an angular directive that does expect a template.